# integration and deployment for .net based applications

Tags: .net, jenkins, msbuild

Before i jump into the question, let me give a background on what i have been doing. I have been searching and reading countless docs that fails to clarify my quest for the solution. There is no clear explanation. Some docs/discussions are too old or some mention about msdeploy but failed to give a proper 'How To'.

This is about the CI-CD on a .NET based application. At the moment, for the CI & CD, i use `msbuild` as it can be scripted. I am using it via `Jenkins`, but it doesn't matter here as it is there to just execute the commands.

`MSBuild` does the code compilation based on the `configuration` (viz: debug, release, stage etc) and use the option `publishprofile`. Below is an example of the command that compiles the solution & publishes it to the lab environment:

COMMAND#1: 
`msbuild.exe /p:Configuration=Lab /m:4 /nr:false /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=Lab AppSourcing.sln`

Its compiles the code and deploys to the endpoint which is specified in the `publishprofile`. I am using the publish-method as `file-system`. So it basically just copies over the files to the defined path of the IIS server.

Now the problem is, to deploy to every environments like QA, staging etc. I have to re execute the commands like:

COMMAND#2: 
`msbuild.exe /p:Configuration=Lab /m:4 /nr:false /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=QA AppSourcing.sln`

COMMAND#3: 
`msbuild.exe /p:Configuration=Lab /m:4 /nr:false /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=Staging AppSourcing.sln`

To get around this issue of building for each environment, what i do is to use files generated by COMMAND#1 by zipping them up and deploy them in the other environments but with different web configs. The deploy process copies & extracts the zip folder in the right endpoints defined in the respective `publishprofile`  files + a command to `copy` over the respective web.config file. This is possible as the `configurations` (i think) are not different between each environments.

Is there a better way of handling this or do you see any loophole in this approach? i am looking for a standard way to build a .net code and deploy it to multiple environments

Answer (score 0):

YES, there is a better way!  You need to use WebDeploy/MSDeploy packages. We use them as our foundation for deploying 50+ products to all our different environments (DEV, QA, MOCK, PROD, etc). MSDeploy packages support parameterization which allow you to define configurations that need to change at deploy time.

http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2016/04/16/msbuild-once-msdeploy-many-times/

Here is a general overview of WebDeploy:

http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2016/02/25/the-anatomy-of-a-webdeploy-package/

We also use WebDeploy/MSDeploy to deploy non-web applications:

http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2016/03/18/deploy-non-web-apps-with-msdeploy/
http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2016/02/10/deploying-a-database-project-with-msdeploy/